# Database logon failed. after postback in crystal report

Tags: database, crystal-reports, connection, report

I connect database to crystal report in runtime by the either of following code, but it loses the database connection in postback (when I click in treeview or trying to navigate to next page)
this is the error I got:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Database logon failed.

```
            ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            cryRpt.Load(path);
```

(((1)))

```
            for (int i = 0; i < cryRpt.DataSourceConnections.Count; i++)
                cryRpt.DataSourceConnections[i].SetConnection(ServerName, DatabaseName, UserID, Password);
            for (int i = 0; i < cryRpt.Subreports.Count; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < cryRpt.Subreports[i].DataSourceConnections.Count; j++)
                    cryRpt.OpenSubreport(cryRpt.Subreports[i].Name).DataSourceConnections[j].SetConnection(ServerName, DatabaseName, UserID, Password);

                    cryRpt.OpenSubreport(cryRpt.Subreports[i].Name).DataSourceConnections[j].SetConnection(ServerName, DatabaseName, UserID, Password);
```

(((2)))

```
            crConnectionInfo.ServerName = ServerName;
            crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = DatabaseName;
            crConnectionInfo.UserID = UserID;
            crConnectionInfo.Password = Password;
            crDatabase = cryRpt.Database;
            crTables = crDatabase.Tables;

            for (int i = 0; i < crTables.Count; i++)
            {
                crTable = crTables[i];
                crTableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
                crTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogOnInfo);
                //crTable.Location = crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName + ".dbo." + crTable.Location.Substring(crTable.Location.LastIndexOf(".") + 1) 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you postback the CrystalReportViewer is losing the report with a valid connection.

Add the line where I store the cryRpt in session to your existing report loading code. Per below, place this combined code into a routine only run on initial page load:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    // do all your normal code loading you did in your OP
    // add this line to store the ReportDocument
    Session["myReport"] = cryRpt;
    crReportViewer.ReportSource = cryRpt;
    crReportViewer.Show();
}
```

Then place this code in the else (when we ARE posting back) to get our ReportDocument from session and reassign it to the CrystalReportViewer control.

```
else
{
    // this is when you postback
    // (i.e. paging, drilling into tree view, exporting, printing)        
    crReportViewer.ReportSource = (ReportDocument)Session["myReport"];
    crReportViewer.Show();
}
```

Comment: Right, and my code suggests a solution for it. By placing the report document into session (and retrieving it for the CrystalReportViewer control on postbacks) the 'database logon failed' error should no longer appear.

Comment: Also, if you post your *complete* current code into the OP it'd be easier to troubleshoot it.